# How do I parse an RSA public key in Go?

Tags: go

Why do I get the error `ssh: short read` from the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "testing"
)

func TestPublicKeyParsing(t *testing.T) {
    key := "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDhZgLqiZYDKCWhyi2gUXIRwIPyMSyXZ6yrwsm3PYfIvFB60kVlNgqDpPVhWoH6eRfaQ1y/xbg4nClZmHEDTvLbTQ1ZoQzzjZ7zvM6aQ4nADmKcCYswEuU94axouVjsHNyMLfOkPXuGec0fChwQ2JDh/B9LCiSDxyhCOgHvETXGXsyBMKjn498iPjJ6snzk35dy5wPZRz41g3dLaygF+wYAT791u/JchHQL7OP7RoNgby+RM16SYZs1tgQVkfU//o+AyTarWYLVDpFU6HPPenE4xEXhbgqd7x3wSNPBsMvY8Zjcu3kdHtboJidyMtKeD8ghV/T24kME58TW15T8Eg8R"

    _, err := ssh.ParsePublicKey([]byte(key))
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("ERROR! %s", err)
    }
}
```

Is the key string in the wrong format?

What is the correct format for the public key?

Comment: I think you want [ParseAuthorizedKey](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseAuthorizedKey) instead

Comment: @Peter yes! you're right. please create an answer and I'll accept it. thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This looks like the authorized_keys format, which you can parse with [ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ParseAuthorizedKey):

```golang
package main

import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "testing"
)

func TestPublicKeyParsing(t *testing.T) {
    key := "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDhZgLqiZYDKCWhyi2gUXIRwIPyMSyXZ6yrwsm3PYfIvFB60kVlNgqDpPVhWoH6eRfaQ1y/xbg4nClZmHEDTvLbTQ1ZoQzzjZ7zvM6aQ4nADmKcCYswEuU94axouVjsHNyMLfOkPXuGec0fChwQ2JDh/B9LCiSDxyhCOgHvETXGXsyBMKjn498iPjJ6snzk35dy5wPZRz41g3dLaygF+wYAT791u/JchHQL7OP7RoNgby+RM16SYZs1tgQVkfU//o+AyTarWYLVDpFU6HPPenE4xEXhbgqd7x3wSNPBsMvY8Zjcu3kdHtboJidyMtKeD8ghV/T24kME58TW15T8Eg8R"

    parsedKey, _, _, _, err := ssh.ParseAuthorizedKey([]byte(key))
    if err != nil {
        t.Errorf("ERROR! %s", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but I'm still curious: But what format is `ssh.ParsePublicKey` expecting?

Comment: @dataprincess, it's the OpenSSH format: https://linux.die.net/man/8/sshd (AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT section)